# Como exibir o valor de 8.0E-5 com php

Tags: php, number-format

Opa, alguém sabe como converter esse **8.0E-5** valor para seu valor original?

Comment: consegui resolver Obg..
`$Valor = '8.0E-5';
printf("%0.7f", $Valor);`

Comment: coloque isso como resposta da sua pergunta, isso é muito válido aqui ...